# angular router resolver - get params from parent on reload

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-resolver

I have a route like this, with a resolver for a child route.

```
 {
        path: 'organizations/:oid',
        component: AdminOrganizationComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'profile',
            component: AdminOrganizationProfileComponent,
            resolve: { organization: OrganizationResolver }
          },
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'profile', pathMatch: 'full' }
        ]
      },
```

The resolver looks like this

```
@Injectable()
export class OrganizationResolver implements Resolve<Observable<Organization>> {
  private activeOrganization: Organization;
  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) {}

  setUser(organization: Organization) {
    this.activeOrganization = organization;
  }

  resolve() {
    return of(this.activeOrganization);
  }
}
```

Before I navigate to the route, I use the service to set the selected organization.

```
  edit(organization) {
    this.organizationResolver.setUser(organization);
    this.router.navigate(['/admin/organizations', organization.id]);
  }
```

So far it works just as intended, I can use `snapshot.data` to get the selected organization.

Now when I reload the route

> /organizations/12345/profile

I want the resolver to check if there is a `activeOrganization` stored. If not, it is supposed to retrieve it via a `http.get` with the `12345` as `id`.

My problem is that i don't know with which tool I can retrieve the params. Normally in a component I can simple use `activatedRoute.parent.params`
But in this case the injected `activatedRoute.parent` is `null`.

I figured that since I've provided the resolver in root, `parent=null` would make sense but logging out the snapshot I'm getting `null` in parent as well as `firstChild`...

Comment: so you want to get params inside resolver?

Comment: yes, thats right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ActivatedRouteSnapshot  Contains the information about a route
>   associated with a component loaded in an outlet at a particular moment
>   in time. ActivatedRouteSnapshot can also be used to traverse the
>   router state tree.

```
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    let id: any = route.params['id'];
  }
```

Comment: I just found it also myself :D, but thanks a ton anyway!